# Trouble getting Webclient to work with SSL

Tags: java, webclient, reactor-netty

The problem I'm having is similar to issue [#640](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/640) on the reactor-netty github and I used the code that @violetagg used with JVM arguments for all my keystore and truststore parameters as well as the noOpenSsl=true flag, but I always get a bad certificate error. I have tracked down with a breakpoint at line 861 of sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker in the serverHelloDone method that the sslContext.getX509KeyManager() returns a DummyX509KeyManager thus not returning any certificates and giving a "Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication" error in the network SSL debugging. Calling the same server with an AsyncRestTemplate or a FeignClient returns a key manager and data from the server. The ClientHandshaker code is in the openjdk for 1.8. Any ideas? I'm running:

Reactor Netty version
0.9.7.RELEASE

JVM version (e.g. java -version)
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

OS version (e.g. uname -a)
Linux m2 4.15.3-041503-generic #201802120730 SMP Mon Feb 12 07:31:14 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am using https. Here is the code that calls a server created from the example at:

https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security

```
        String block = WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient.create()
                                .secure(spec -> spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient()))))
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri("https://localhost:8443/user")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
```

I do have a certificate installed for localhost.  I installed the certificate from the information at: https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security into the java truststore.  If I had not done that I don't think I could have had the server return data and things work by calling the same server with an AsyncRestTemplate.  The following code works for me while the above does not:

```
        AsyncRestTemplate a = new AsyncRestTemplate();
        ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> exchange = a.exchange("https://localhost:8443/user", 
                HttpMethod.GET, RequestEntity.EMPTY, String.class);
        ResponseEntity<String> block = exchange.get();
```

I am trying to access the site with a client certificate.  It seems that delegating the creation of the SSLContext to Netty loads the truststore, but not the key store.  If I load and add a keystore things work:

```
String keyStoreLocation = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
String keyStorePassword = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStoreLocation)), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

// Set up key manager factory to use our key store
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

String block = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create()
                        .secure(spec -> spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                        .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)))))
        .build()
        .get()
        .uri("https://localhost:8443/user")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
```

Comment: you probably don't have a certificate installed for "localhost" that you trust, do you?

Comment: No, I do have a certificate installed for localhost.  See the edit above.

Comment: I got things to work.  See edit above.

Comment: Ah - adding a KeyManager, I see!